# How to select an ng-option through ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have a table which I am populating using ng-repeat. For examples sake, let's say I'm creating an evite-type mock site and the table is showing everyone that has responded. Each row has a radio button which, when selected, will populate additional information in a div below the table. This div is also used to as the template to reply and update an existing reply. When I select a row from the table above, the fields in this div will be populated. One of the fields is a select drop down box which is populated using ng-options. These options display "YES", "NO", and "MAYBE" but when sending the response back to services, it is expecting a code number "1", "2", or "3" respectively. My ng-options look like this:

```
ng-options="decision.decisionCode as decision.decisionDescription for decision in vm.decisionList"
```

My question is, when I select a row from the table, I am not able to display the option. I tried to set the ng-model of the select to the decisionCode, decisionDescription and the object, but the drop down remains blank. How can I assign the ng-model for the select to display the selected value from the table?

```
<div class="col-md-2 ">
    <select class="form-control" id="decision" ng-model="vm.decisionSelected" ng-options="decision.decisionCode as decision.decisionDescription for decision in vm.decisionList"></select>
</div>
```

vm.decisionList:

```
[{
"decisionCode": "1",
"decisionDescription": "YES"
}, {
"decisionCode": "2",
"decisionDescription": "NO"
}, {
"decisionCode": "3",
"decisionDescription": "MAYBE"
}]
```

Comment: Please include the whole `select` html (with the `ng-model`) and show us how your `vm.decisionList` looks like

Comment: Updated with requested information

Comment: And what does your `vm.decisionSelected` look like?

Comment: @devqon vm.decisionSelected is the decisionCode of the selected decisionDescription (ie: if YES is selected from drop down, vm.decisionSelected is 1

Comment: Is it `1` or is it `"1"`? The type must be the same with `ng-options` (number vs string)

Comment: It is a string in the options as well as the decisionSelected

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works fine for me. One thing you should look into is how you set up your controller. I am assuming you are using Controller As syntax considering your snippet, so your controller will have to at a minimum look like this:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('myController', myController);

function myController() {
    var vm = this;             // This is necessary for Controller As syntax to work
    vm.decisionSelected = "1"; // Assuming you want a default value
    vm.decisionList = [
        {
            "decisionCode": "1",
            "decisionDescription": "YES"
        }, 
        {
            "decisionCode": "2",
            "decisionDescription": "NO"
        }, 
        {
            "decisionCode": "3",
            "decisionDescription": "MAYBE"
        }];
}
```

If instead of this, you are making vm.decisionList a $scope variable so that it is $scope.decisionList, it will not be recognized by the Controller As syntax, so you would need to drop the "vm." in your ng-options

Comment: That is very similar to how my controller looks. When I use an expression to view my model, I am seeing the correct value. The problem is, that value is not being associated to the correct response from the drop down list. So, for example, if I select a row from the table where the response is "YES", then the model is assigned "1" as it should. However, the drop down list that contains the ng-options does not populate with the correct response.